# hdf5.h no such file or directory under Ubuntu and CMake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, hdf5

I have already installed HDF5 under Ubuntu :

```
sudo apt install libhdf5-dev
```

I have a Qt program using HDF5 that compiles fine under CentOS 7 but not under Ubuntu :

> erreur : hdf5.h: No such file or directory  #include 
>             ^~~~~~~~

I am using CMake to generate the build files and in it, I didn't need to handle HDF5 for the CentOS build.

I added this part that I found on the web to the CMake script but I still have a compile error.

```
FIND_PACKAGE(ZLIB)
FIND_LIBRARY(HDF5_LIBRARY hdf5 ...)
FIND_LIBRARY(HDF5_HL_LIBRARY hdf5_hl ...)
IF(NOT TARGET hdf5 AND NOT TARGET hdf5_hl)
    ADD_LIBRARY(hdf5 SHARED IMPORTED)
    ADD_LIBRARY(hdf5_hl SHARED IMPORTED)
ENDIF()
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hdf5 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${HDF5_LIBRARY})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hdf5_hl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                                         ${HDF5_HL_LIBRARY})
SET(HDF5_LIBRARIES hdf5 hdf5_hl ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} m)
```

What can I add to the script to fix the include problem ?

with "locate", I found different hdf5.h :

```
/usr/include/hdf5/mpich/hdf5.h
/usr/include/hdf5/openmpi/hdf5.h
/usr/include/hdf5/serial/hdf5.h
```

I really want to know what "libhdf5-dev" refers to ? and why HDF5 is not provided correctly under Ubuntu (it's crazy !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Ubuntu, I was forced to add MPI to the CMake script. I don't like this solution but its CMake and Ubuntu fault...

```
find_package(HDF5)
find_package(MPI)

....

target_link_libraries(${binary} ${MPI_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_LIBRARIES} ... )

target_include_directories(${binary} PRIVATE ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

there's also this question : [Using serial HDF5 C++ with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561033/using-serial-hdf5-c-with-cmake)

libhdf5-dev is, in fact, the serial version https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libhdf5-dev/filelist

Comment: Why do you need to add MPI if the package is the serial version?

Comment: Because CMake is not aware of the serial version, if I don't add MPI, I will have link errors.

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the documentation of [imported targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets), you also have to populate `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` to specify headers location. You may want to add the dependency for HL as well with `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`.

So that would be something like:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hdf5 PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I think this is also the one that you want to specify properly:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hdf5 PROPERTIES INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} m)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hdf5_hl PROPERTIES INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES hdf5)
```

Instead of your `HDF5_LIBRARIES` change.

Comment: I got this error SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES called with incorrect number of arguments.

Comment: `HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS` should be defined if you used `find_package(HDF5)`. If you are not using the package, please do, or set the normal expected variables. Otherwise, of course `HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS` is not going to be set to the proper path!

Comment: I've done this to fix the issue : SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(hdf5 PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/usr/include/hdf5/serial/")

Comment: You're right ! find_package(HDF5) fixed the problem !

Comment: at the end of compilation, I got this error : :-1: erreur : No rule to make target 'HDF5_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND', needed by 'MY-APPLICATION'.  Stop.

Comment: This means that HDF5 was not found properly.

Comment: I have another problem now : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_cxx.so.20:-1: erreur : error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line CMake it using the MPI HDF5

Comment: Apparently, I need the "serial HDF5" not the mpi one, how to indiciate to CMake that (God damn ubuntu !)

Comment: Not sure, never had a problem selecting serial HDF or even parallel HDF with the package :/ But you can always set the variables manually, as you did for the rest on your first iteration.

Comment: why /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_cxx.so.20 is linked ? I have this error  undefined reference to symbol '_ZN3MPI8Datatype4FreeEv'

Comment: That's because the libraries that were detected are probably MPI libraries indeed.