# proper way to write a CMakeLists referencing HDF5 in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake, hdf5

I've already downloaded an built HDF5 under Windows using CMake, I also generated an installer to install it under Program Files.

Below the CMakeLists.txt I wrote to be able to use HDF5 in a program I already wrote under Linux :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Hdf5DataFeed)

add_definitions(-DWINDOWS)

find_package(HDF5)
FIND_LIBRARY(HDF5_HL_LIBRARY hdf5_hl)
FIND_LIBRARY(ZLIB zlib)
find_library(ZMQ_LIB zmq)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

include_directories(${ZMQ_LIB_INCLUDE})

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ZLIB} "C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.1/lib/libszip.lib"  ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${ZMQ_LIB} ${HDF5_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_HL_LIBRARY} Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

As you can see above, to link HDF5 under Visual Studio, I needed Zlib, Szip (that I had to enter an absolute path to it, I don't like that), HDF5 library and the HDF5 High Level (Lite) library.

These libraries are located under C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.10.1\lib :

```
libhdf5.lib <============
libhdf5.settings
libhdf5_cpp.lib
libhdf5_hl.lib <=====
libhdf5_hl_cpp.lib
libhdf5_tools.lib
libszip.lib <=== ????
libzlib.lib <====
```

I use CMake-Gui to inform CMake of the libraries path (except for Szip, I don't know why CMake doesn't know about it, and why I don't have the possibility to just feed CMake the library directory instead of indicating the path of few of them).

I want to use CMake-GUI to inform CMake of Szip library path, but this last doesn't create an entry of it, I only have these entries related to HDF5 :

[image: HDF5 CMake entries]

I'm having troubles with HDF5 also under Ubuntu (see this question : [hdf5.h no such file or directory under Ubuntu and CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370647/hdf5-h-no-such-file-or-directory-under-ubuntu-and-cmake/54373693)).

For now, it's only under CentOS 7 that I didn't encounter any issues with HDF5.

If someone can give me/us a final solution that works both on Windows and Ubuntu that would be great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For libszip, adding a find_library is better than putting an absolute link to it. For ZLib, it is preferable to use find_library as find_package will require you to feed CMake with an include directory which is not required for HDF5. Finally, it is preferable to use find_package for ZMQ, otherwise, we need to add manually the entry "ZMQ_LIB_INCLUDE".

Answer (score 1):

Does this solution work for you?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Hdf5DataFeed)

# necessary?
add_definitions(-DWINDOWS)

find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS C CXX HL)
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
find_library(ZMQ_LIB zmq)

include_directories(${ZMQ_LIB_INCLUDE} ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR} 
  ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${HDF5_LIBRARIES}
  ${HDF5_HL_LIBRARIES} ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES} 
  Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets ${ZMQ_LIB})
```

**Recommendation 1:** Surely, there is a way to find Qt5 via find_package, i.e.,

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)
```

and then add the correct variables to include_directories and target_link_libraries. Not sure whether such a possibility exists for the zmq library, though.

**Recommendation 2:** I think the call the aux_source_directory should be avoided in most cases. Create an explicit list of your source files instead.

Comment: I don't have my Windows PC right know, I will check it tomorrow ! Thanks.